# Need help styling PHP in HTML

Tags: php, html, css, database, text-styling

This is my PHP coding from which I am grabbing data from my DB with a select where statement and outputting it. I am trying to change the text properties such as font, colour and size on the print statement can anybody assis with how to do this?

```
<?php
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT fname, sname FROM tbl_stylist WHERE fname = 'liza'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        print " - Name: " . $row["fname"]. " " . $row["sname"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Are you getting results back from your MySQL query?

Comment: Use HTML-tags and CSS stlyes to style it. Shouldn't be a big deal to get that done.

Comment: Hi  you can put one div tag and write  some css property like this <div class = "sampleclass">   </div>  and write css property in that class

Answer (score 2):

You can style lists using HTML `<ul>` and `<li>` elements.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Stylists</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT fname, sname FROM tbl_stylist WHERE fname = 'liza'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo "<ul>";

    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<li>Name: " . $row["fname"]. " " . $row["sname"]. "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?></body>
</html>
```

And in `css/style.css` put something like this:

```
li {
   color: red;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 12pt;
}
```

You can also put the style inline in the head section:

```
<style type="text/css">
li {
   color: red;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 12pt;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Hi Adder this does not seem to working for some reason?

Comment: In which way isn't it working? Do you get an error message?

Comment: No error message at all.. page is loading as normal but no changes have shown in regards to the text on page from the echo statement

Comment: Did you create a `css` directory with file `style.css` in it containing styling for `<li>` ?

Comment: Yes I already have a CSS directory created under default.css with all my CSS styles within it and I added the <li> style to it yet no joy

Comment: Do the balls in front of every line show up for the code `echo "<li>Name: " . $row["fname"]. " " . $row["sname"]. "</li>";`? Can you show your css? Also do a shift-click reload to purge the cache of old copies of your css file.

Answer (score 1):

You can output your markdown like this:

```
print "<div class = 'sampleclass'>  - Name: " . $row["fname"]. " " .
```

Then style it by including the below in an attached `css` file

```
.sampleclass {
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Hi Mathan I have attempted to do this and have had no luck in it working

Comment: did you wrote  css property in top of the page

Answer (score 0):

This is only about HTML and CSS, you could output directly your strings in HTML tags with echo. The script needs to be encapsulated into the HTML's body and a pre-defined CSS classes for styling:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    ....
    <style type="text/css">
      .redBold {
         color: red;
         font-weight: bold;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      ....
      echo '<span class="redBold">This text is red and bold</span>';
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Of course you can also use inline styling:

```html
<span style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">Also this works</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use CSS file and define the values.
For example:

```
body {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    php txt
  </body>
</html>
```

Also, you can use `<span>` tags and style them.
For example print this span using 'print' of php:

```
<span style="font-family: arial; font-size: 15px;">text</span>
```